# Spring Rabbit Supports What Versions of RabbitMQ?

Tags: spring, rabbitmq

I am currently on Spring Rabbit 2.4.7 and plan to upgrade RabbitMQ to 3.11. Is there a way to know whether this is supported? I have reviewed the documentation and reviewed other threads where @gary-russell has replied, but am trying to see if anything has changed recently.

Comment: `org.springframework.amqp:spring-rabbit:2.4.7` or `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-amqp:2.4.7` ??
Check the dependencies of the packages and the compatibility of the Rabbit Java Client version will be interesting for you.

Comment: @Numichi I am using org.springframework.amqp:spring-rabbit:2.4.7

Comment: If everything is true, it can be working with RabbitMQ 3.11. But, if you would like to deploy to the prod before it is worth testing on a test environment. Because `org.springframework.amqp:spring-rabbit:2.4.7` is using RabbitMQ Java Client 5.13.1. Currently 5.16.0 is latest and I have not seen breaking change note in release note.